# Issue looping on deadletter message count >4500 to invoke Abandon() on it and print xml in file

Tags: c#, servicebus

I am trying to receive the deadletter messages and output the xml in a file and invoke Abandon() on the message. My deadletter message count is greater than 4500. But the ReceiveBatch() method does not allow me to fetch more than 4500 messages. And if i implement a while loop on that, then it keeps on repeating the same set of 4500 deadlettered messages.

Can anyone please help me with C# code to be able to fetch more than 4500 messages or to be able to instruct the ReceiveBatch method to continue with next set of 4500 messages so that I can loop through all the deadlettered message coount that i see in Service Bus Explorer for my queue.

**P.S.** What I have understood so far is ReceiveBatch method does not keep a track of the last sequencenumber that it pulled and so is this issue of repeatition. I tried combining PeekBatch method with ReceiveBatch method to see if PeekBatch method's sequencenumber tracking capability helps me fix this issue as below, but that as did not work beyong 4500 messages:

Here's the code block that I have written to iterate on the batch of messages (preferrably more than 4500 count):

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, DeadletterProcessor.Properties.Settings.Default.QueuePath); 

client.PrefetchCount = 50000; 

Func<int, IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>> getBatch = (batchSize) => 
{ 
lock (readQueueLock)
{ 
    return client.ReceiveBatch(batchSize, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
} 
}; 

IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> batch = null; 

while (client.PeekBatch(4500) != null) 
{
  batch = getBatch(4500); 
  Console.WriteLine(batch.Count()); 

  foreach (var message in batch) 
  {
    try
    {
      //Parse details from SOAP message and writes xml in .txt file
      Output(message);

      message.Abandon(); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Please help me with some example to fix this issue. Any help will be greatly appreicated.

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, DeadletterProcessor.Properties.Settings.Default.QueuePath);
client.PrefetchCount = 50000;
Func<int, IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>> getBatch = (batchSize) =>
{  lock (readQueueLock){
       return client.ReceiveBatch(batchSize, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));}
 }; 
IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> batch = null;
while (client.PeekBatch(4500) != null) {batch = getBatch(4500);
                Console.WriteLine(batch.Count());
 foreach (var message in batch)
 {try{Output(message); //writes xml in .txt file   message.Abandon();
 }        }}

Comment: Hi, Can someone please help with the above query. It is becoming a roadbloack in my project. Would greatly appreciate a quicker response.   Thanks

Comment: edit the question and put the code in there

Comment: I have already added the code block which gets executed for the batch of messages in my last comment. Please let me know if you are not able to see it.

Comment: yes you added it in the comments.  please add it to the question

Comment: I have edited the question with code snippet. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, Is anyone able to figure out what the issue might be with the above code? I am running out of time, so any quicker help would greatly help.   Thank you!

Comment: Hi tim,  Do you have any idea with the above code? Can you please help on that?   Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds nasty... could you perhaps move the dead letters into another topic or subscription? It's a bit hacky, but then you could have 4500 per subscription or topic to work with, rather than 4500 overall.

Comment: Also, do you really need to keep them there once you have the XML for your Output() call? You could delete them rather than Abandon()ing them perhaps? Or even resubmit them to the topic.

Comment: Hi Baggy, we usually do not delete the messages in deadletter queue, when it expires, its removed on its own. And so we needed an approach by which we could loop through all deadletter messages while printing their soap xml and still retaining those messages in deadletter queue(calling Abandon() on them). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't had to deal with this problem sorry. I guess it depends where this 4500 limitation is coming from. I just thought I'd suggest some possible workarounds.